# Python resample by day & get weekstart data

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have monthly data. When I apply resampling by day and cubic interpolation, there is a function to find the month end data

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name='mthly', usecols='A:D', na_values='ND', index_col=0, header=0)
df.index.names = ['Period']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

q= pd.Series(df[series], index=df.index)
d = q.resample('D').interpolate(method='cubic')  
m=d[d.index.is_month_end]
```

Now I want the data for the start of each week, but I can't find such a function. How do I solve this?

**INPUT MONTHLY DATA**

```
Period  Values
Jan-22  1
Feb-22  3
Mar-22  7
Apr-22  5
May-22  4
```

**After re-sampling by day and with cubic interpolation**

```
Period
2022-01-01    1.000000
2022-01-02    0.884487
2022-01-03    0.785650
2022-01-04    0.703004
2022-01-05    0.636066
2022-01-06    0.584353
2022-01-07    0.547382
2022-01-08    0.524668
2022-01-09    0.515729
2022-01-10    0.520081
2022-01-11    0.537240
2022-01-12    0.566724
2022-01-13    0.608048
and so on
```

**Desired output is Monday of each week**

```
2022-01-03    0.785650
2022-01-10    0.520081
and so on
```

Thank you

Comment: @Panda Kim: Have provided the input data. Hope u can help! Thanks

Comment: what is your desired output of input data? if you make desired ouput like input data, many people can help you

Comment: @ Panda Kim: I don't really know how the desired output will look. But It should be selecting the monday of each week

Comment: Then  create simple example from which you can predict outcome, and  provide example and output

Comment: @Panda Kim:  Have updated with desired output. Pls assist. Thanks

Comment: For answer, simple example and desired output are required. Your effort can greatly reduce time wasted on the respondent. It is more convenient if you also provide code of  example like I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'Period': {0: 'Jan-22', 1: 'Feb-22', 2: 'Mar-22', 3: 'Apr-22', 4: 'May-22'},
        'Values': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 7, 3: 5, 4: 4}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    Period      Values
0   2022-01-01  1
1   2022-02-01  3
2   2022-03-01  7
3   2022-04-01  5
4   2022-05-01  4
```

---

**Code**

use `asfreq` for upsampling

```
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'], format='%b-%y') # change to datetime
out = (df.set_index('Period').asfreq(freq='D')
       .interpolate(method='cubic')[lambda x: x.index.weekday == 0])
```

`out.head(5)`

```
            Values
Period  
2022-01-03  0.785650
2022-01-10  0.520081
2022-01-17  0.882085
2022-01-24  1.705848
2022-01-31  2.825552
```

---

**note**

[pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html)

`.weekday` return weekday by number(mon = 0, sum =6) in DatetimeIndex

*example*

```
idx1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'])
```

`idx1`

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

```
idx1.weekday
```

```
Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

when applied to datetime series instead datetimeindex, The dt accessor is required  (ex: `dt.weekday`)

Comment: Thanks v much for the answer. But if I want to find the middle day of every month? Thanks!

Comment: what means middle day? if jan, 16th day?

Comment: Middle day = round(total number of day in month/2)

Comment: you can get day of month by `day` attribute. you can get month by `month` attribute, like `weekday` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html

Comment: and i think you can search and you can find way.  when i solved question, there is tendency to solve everything with additional questions to answerer. i feel sorry meet that. so i solve only question with simple example and output.